# How Firm to hold Bansuri

Tags: posture, bansuri

I understand that one must blow softly on Bansuri, as if cooling a food item.

But what about how firm to hold Bansuri. I noticed my hands got tired after 6 minutes of playing because I held onto the Bansuri holes tightly.

Any guidance?

Comment: It's somewhat like beginners playing guitar. They feel they have to press really, really hard on the strings. After a while, they realise that just enough pressure does the job just as well. You must do the same. By closing a hole really really hard, is it better than just closing the hole? Of course not, so experiment and use *sufficient* finger pressure over the holes, not more than is needed. Balance of the bansuri will also mean no need to hold on to the instrument to stop it falling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with any wind instrument you should only hold the instrument tightly enough to keep it stable, but no tighter. The problem with any flute type instrument is the **balance** and that takes some practice to get secure. Once you have the instrument balanced in your hands you need almost no finger pressure, just enough to keep the holes fully closed. Concentrate on precise finger movement rather than strength.
One cause of your hand tiredness might be the finger **stretch**, particularly if you are playing a larger instrument. You just need to start slowly and build up your endurance.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to describe "how to hold" without showing ...  Assuming you have a bass bansuri, otherwise the grip is pretty straight forward.
The fingers should lay on the holes without any force. Make sure you can hold the flute in balanced position with all of the holes open. Then try to to close the first three holes with your left hand fingers (I assume you're right handed) by just laying down the fingers on the holes. The index finger should cover the hole with a knuckle ,same with the second hole. only the ring finger should cover the hole with a tip.
The same goes with the right hand — just lay the fingers down on the holes in a natural manner, and that should be the basic grip from which you can begin.